# Why is a value with an explicit type annotation generalized here?

Tags: f#, value-restriction

I'm getting a VR error on a let binding on module scope saying one of its parameters is a generic, but I don't know why that parameter is generic in the first place. This is the code:

```
let private asJsonResponse (responseSource: _ Task) =
    fun (next: HttpFunc) (ctx: HttpContext) ->
        task {
            let! consumption = responseSource
            return! json consumption next ctx
        }

let getVal = someFuncThatReturnsTaskOfMyType() |> asJsonResponse
```

The error is on the last line:

> error FS0030: Value restriction. The value `getVal` has been inferred to have generic type
> `val getVal: (HttpFunc -> '_a -> Task<HttpContext option>)` when `'_a :> HttpContext`
> Either make the arguments to `getVal` explicit or, if you do not intend for it to be generic, add a type annotation.

I understand that it essentially generalizes `ctx: HttpContext` to *something that can be cast to `HttpContext`*. Why does this happen? And why only for this parameter and not `next: HttpFunc`?

`HttpContext` is a class and `HttpFunc` is a function type, is that the problem?

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the code you're working with? Could it be that you forgot to recompile a module after making a change?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I did a full rebuild before posting here to verify, the code is copy pasted from my source file (except some name changes).

Comment: Try adding type annotations all over the place and see what happens. In this case, I'm guessing a type annotation on `asJsonResponse` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles if you either add type annotations:

```
let getVal: HttpFunc -> HttpContext -> Task<HttpContext option> =
    someFuncThatReturnsTaskOfMyType() |> asJsonResponse
```

Or add explicit parameter:

```
let getVal f = asJsonResponse (someFuncThatReturnsTaskOfMyType()) f
```

The simple answer is that type inferring mechanism of the F# compiler isn't perfect. You can read about this [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/troubleshooting-fsharp/#FS0030) :

> The F# compiler tries to guess the most generalized type possible that
> will fit, but in some cases, the compiler feels that the code is
> ambiguous, and, even though it looks like it is guessing the type
> correctly, it needs you to be more specific

and for more specific details, here is the documentation:

[MSDN Automatic Generalisation in F#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd233183(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) have some examples of it

> Typically, the value restriction error occurs either when you want a
> construct to be generic but the compiler has insufficient information
> to generalize it, or when you unintentionally omit sufficient type
> information in a nongeneric construct.